# How to Update Stats and Rebuild Indexes in Azure Geo-Replicated Database

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-sql-database, database-replication

I have a Geo-Replicated Azure SQL Database which has some serious index fragmentation and outdated statistics.

An attempt to REORGANIZE or REBUILD an index, or to UPDATE STATISTICS results in the message **"Failed to update database xxx because the database is read-only."** however a quick check against sys.databases shows that the database is in fact not in READ_ONLY mode.

Understandably Azure manages the database as it is a geo-replicated copy, so my question is that if I request that Indexes and Statistics updates are implemented on the MASTER copy, whether my replicated copy will receive same, or is there a way to update on my replicated copy alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All statements you run on the primary database to rebuild indexes and maintain statistics will also be executed on the secondary. For more information click [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2016/10/31/lesson-learned-8-monitoring-the-geo-replicated-databases/).